# Showing a JDialog whenever there is an exception

Tags: java, exception-handling, error-handling, gui

I have made a method which I use to show the exception error through a `JDialog` window whenever there is one in my program.

For now I can pass it either a String or a subclass of `Exception`. At first I had two different methods for each one but now I combined them into one.

**The `showError` method:**

```
public static void showError(Object error) {
        String mainMessage = null;
        String title = null;
        if (error instanceof String) {
            mainMessage = (String) error;
            title = "Error!";
        } else if (error instanceof Exception) {
            Exception exceptionError = (Exception) error;
            mainMessage = "Message: " + exceptionError.getMessage()
                    + "\nStackTrace: " + Arrays.toString(exceptionError.getStackTrace());
            title = exceptionError.getClass().getName();
        }

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, mainMessage, title, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> At first I had two different methods for each one but now I combined
>   them into one.

I would have made 3 methods instead of one.

```
public static void showError(String errorMessage) {
    showError(errorMessage, "Error!");
}
```

---

```
public static void showError(Exception exceptionError) {
    String errorMessage = "Message: " + exceptionError.getMessage()
                + "\nStackTrace: " + Arrays.toString(exceptionError.getStackTrace());
    String title = exceptionError.getClass().getName();
    showError(errorMessage, title);
}
```

---

```
public static void showError(String errorMessage, String title) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, errorMessage, title, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

In this way the readability is improved, unnecessary checks are removed as well as casts. 
And it is easier to maintain.

Comment: It looks better the way you have it I believe. One question though, should I pass the Component as a variable or could I just leave it null with no problems?

Comment: based on the docs [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html) you can leave it as null